# how to execute a query having using order by

Tags: c#

I want to display data with respect to names. i.e order by name but my query is not working properly. It is displaying all the data but not in a sequence.

```
string select_failed_students = "SELECT * FROM awardlist_annual_view WHERE name IN ('" + 
                                string.Join("','", student_name) + 
                                "') ORDER BY name";

DataTable dt_failed_student = DataAccess.selectData(select_failed_students);
gazette_dataGridView.DataSource = dt_failed_student;
```

Comment: Is the DataGridView applying its own sort?

Comment: yes it is applying its own sort..

Answer (score 2):

The `DataView` is maintaining its own sorting. See the example on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can find further examples [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dataview) which will get you familiarized with the necessary concepts. It is important to grasp the difference between the `DataTable` and the `DataView`. The first contains the data, whereas the latter acts as viewing abstraction on top of the first. Note, that you can also have more than one `DataView` bound to the same `DataTable`.

So in your example, you can omit the `ORDER BY` in the `SELECT` query and instead apply the `Sort` property of the view.

If you are using the `DataGridView` control, set it `SortOrder` property as shown in the example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortorder(v=vs.110).aspx).